# Show corresponding div of each anchor on click

Tags: javascript, html

Say I have some simple Html

What I want to do is open the right pane for each anchor without having to checking by the name

```html
<div class="nav">
  <a id="nav1 active">Tab 1</a>
  <a id="nav2">Tab 2</a>
  <a id="nav3">Tab 3</a>
</div>
<div id="pane1 show">Content 1</div>
<div id="pane2">Content 2</div>
<div id="pane3">Content 3</div>
```

```js
const navs = document.querySelectorAll('.nav > a');
nav.forEach(nav => {
    nav.addEventListener('click', addActiveClass => {
    });
});
```

Comment: You want to show the corresponding div with like a class that shows and hides it or you want an anchor that scrolls to the corresponding div ?

Comment: the first one using show for panes and active for anchors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I add a bold CSS class, but the concept is the same for your use case. I also added a toggle logic:

```js
const navs = document.querySelectorAll('nav > a');

navs.forEach((nav) => {
    nav.addEventListener('click', (n) => {
      const panel = document.getElementById(n.target.target)
      document.querySelectorAll(".pane").forEach((pane) => {
        pane.className = pane.className.replace("active", "");
      });
      if(panel){
        panel.className += " active";
      }
    });
});
```

```css
.active {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<nav>
      <a id="nav1" target="pane1">Tab 1</a>
      <a id="nav2" target="pane2">Tab 2</a>
      <a id="nav3" target="pane3">Tab 3</a>
</nav>

<div id="pane1" class="pane">Content 1</div>
<div id="pane2" class="pane">Content 2</div>
<div id="pane3" class="pane">Content 3</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

```js
const navs = document.querySelectorAll('nav > a');
navs.forEach(nav => {
    nav.onclick = function() {
        Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('div')).filter(e => e.id.includes('pane')).forEach(e => {
            e.style.visibility = 'hidden'; //hide all
        });
        document.getElementById('pane' + this.id.split('nav')[1]).style.visibility = 'visible'; //show the clicked one
    };
});
```

```html
<nav>
      <a id="nav1">Tab 1</a>
      <a id="nav2">Tab 2</a>
      <a id="nav3">Tab 3</a>
</nav>

<div id="pane1">Content 1</div>
<div id="pane2">Content 2</div>
<div id="pane3">Content 3</div>
```